# Do I need to use a WSDL to consume a SOAP web service?

Tags: php, web-services

Firstly sorry for the overly broad question but I can't seem to understand this.

I'm in the process of building a phonegap application that will push data to a PHP script which in turn will send XML via SOAP to a web service. I know all the functions of the web service that my script will be using and what data it accepts and returns but am being told by the owner of the web service that I must load the WSDL file into my app to be able to use the web service.

I dont understand why - surely if I know exactly what I'm sending and what I'll receive back, why do I need to import a WSDL file? (I'm not wanting to produce classes from the WSDL file or anything like that).

Again sorry for an overly vague question but I was hoping someone could clear this up for me?

Comment: isn't is easier with WSDL?

Comment: @DoSparKot Why would it be easier with the WSDL?